# I cant display messages from php script to jqgrid page

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid

i'm using JQGRID inline editing , I would like when I do a crud operation then messages should be send back from php script to JQGRID, instead of displaying HTML errors with database values.

I want after I submit, a message should be displayed back from the php script to the user  notifying whether record has been updated, inserted, deleted or created.

At the moment I'm not getting the custom message I have created.

If the record was successfully created I'm not getting any message at all.

If the record was not created for example due to null values send to the database I only get the pop-up page displaying html codes with database error codes, which I don't want it to be displayed but to rather display the message I have created.

I'm using **afterSubmit:** event.

Here is my **afterSubmit:** code.

```
<script>
 {
  afterSubmit: function (response, postdata)
   {
     var json = response.responseText;
     var result = JSON.parse(json);
     return[result.status, result.message, null];
    }
    },
</script>
```

My PHP Code on another page

```
   </php
   public function testing() {
        $data = array(
            'first_name' => 'my fname',
            'surname' => 'my sname',
            'username' => 'my password'
        );

        $this->db->insert('Users', $data);
        $affectedRows = $this->db->affected_rows();

        if ($affectedRows < 0) {
            $message = "Errors";
            $output['status'] = false;
            $output['message'] = $message;
        } else {
            $message = "Success";
            $output['status'] = true;
            $output['message'] = $message;
        }
        return json_encode($output);
    }
?>
```

Comment: You're actually not returning anything from server side. Try to modify your `json_encode` lines into `return json_encode...` and, also, as I see, `json_decode` shouldn't be there - it should be `return json_encode...`

Comment: I have done that, but i'm still getting html error codes instead of the defined messages.

Comment: IMO, it is better to add an example of such errors output (what you are getting) into the question.

Comment: I’m not getting an messages, but I’m getting database errors showing queries, but I don’t want those to display, I want them to be replaced with my custom messages.

Comment: So, that's what I was asking for - an example of that messages. If you're getting db errors instead of your messages - there's possibly an error when you are working with database. Without seeing those errors, I can't help you, sry.